# how to get a boolean value of checkbox whether it is checked or unchecked- android studio?

Tags: android, windows, sqlite

I am using `checkbox` to register a faculty if the `checkbox` is checked, else- by default, student is registered `onClick`. The checkbox value is always checked using the `checkbox.isChecked()`, how do i change it so that it will get the status of the checked/unchecked in `boolean` form. 
i need it in `boolean` since i have used a `boolean` parameter in the Database Helper class in the `insertData()`.

[image: The register activity page (image)]

DatabaseHelper.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="Register.db";
public static final String TABLE_STUDENT ="Register_student";
public static final String TABLE_FACULTY ="Register_faculty";
public static final String TABLE_ATTENDANCE ="Attendance_edit";
public static final String COL_1 ="Name";
public static final String COL_2 ="Username";
public static final String COL_3 ="Password";
public static final String COL_4 ="Roll No";
public static final String COL_5 ="Course Code";
public static final String COL_6 ="Batch";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_STUDENT + "(" +  COL_1
        + " TEXT," + COL_2 + "TEXT," + COL_3
        + " TEXT" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FACULTY = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_FACULTY + "(" +  COL_1
        + " TEXT," + COL_2 + "TEXT," + COL_3
        + " TEXT" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ATTENDANCE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_ATTENDANCE + "(" +  COL_4
        + " TEXT," + COL_5 + "TEXT," + COL_6
        + " TEXT" + ")";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FACULTY);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ATTENDANCE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STUDENT);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FACULTY);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ATTENDANCE);

    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String name, String username, String password,   
boolean checked)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, username);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, password);

    if(!checked) {
      long result=  db.insert(TABLE_STUDENT, null, contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
   else

    { long result = db.insert(TABLE_FACULTY,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

}

public boolean newinsertData(String rollno, String course, String batch)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_4, rollno);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, course);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, batch);
    db.insert(TABLE_ATTENDANCE, null, contentValues);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_FACULTY,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}

public Cursor getAllData()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from" + TABLE_ATTENDANCE, null);


return res;

}

public Cursor ViewData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from" + TABLE_FACULTY, null);
    return result;
}
public Cursor getData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor results = db.rawQuery("select * from" + TABLE_STUDENT, null);
    return results;
}

}
```

The problem is when i use the `insertData` method in the register.java class.

register.java

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity {
Button register, viewdata;
CheckBox faculty;
EditText editName, editUName, editPass;
DatabaseHelper myDB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editUName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    faculty = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox38);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    viewdata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
   register();
    viewdata();
}
public void register() {
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isInserted =    
myDB.insertData(editName.getText().toString(),
                    editUName.getText().toString(),        
editPass.getText().toString(), faculty.isChecked());


            if (isInserted == true) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data added,      
registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not added",           
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    }


        public void viewdata() {
            viewdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (faculty.isChecked()) {
                        Cursor result = myDB.ViewData();

                        if (result.getCount() == 0) {
                            showMessage("Error!", "nothing found");

                            return;
                        }

                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                        while (result.moveToNext()) {
                            buffer.append("Name: " + result.getString(0) + 
 "\n");
                            buffer.append("Username: " + result.getString(1)  
 + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Password: " + result.getString(2)
 + "\n\n");
                        }
                        showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
                    }
                    else {
                        Cursor results = myDB.getData();

                        if (results.getCount() == 0) {
                            showMessage("Error!", "nothing found");

                            return;
                        }

                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                        while (results.moveToNext()) {
                            buffer.append("Name: " + results.getString(0) +     
 "\n");
                            buffer.append("Username: " +  
 results.getString(1) + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Password: " + 
 results.getString(2) + "\n\n");
                        }
                        showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
                    }

                }
            });
        }
public void showMessage (String title, String Message)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}
}
```

Comment: `isChecked()` is the correct method. You've got problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think before you insert the data what you have to do is create a Boolean variable and assign it to true if faculty is checked and false if not, as shown.

```
 public void register() {
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean mybool;
                if (faculty.isChecked()) {
                    mybool = true;

                } else {
                    mybool = false;
                }
                boolean isInserted = myDB.insertData(editName.getText().toString(),
                        editUName.getText().toString(),
                        editPass.getText().toString(), mybool);

                if (isInserted == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data added, registered !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not added",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }//miss the setOnClickListener the close brace
    }//miss the function close brace
```

Comment: Thanx! I did this but i am getting " Data not added" still. why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

String.valueOf(faculty.isChecked())

You might need to convert it to string